# How to extract sub-string from indistinct pattern

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to extract a certain part of a string, but that string may vary in its pattern.

We're talking about a string that defines a bunch of properties, i.e. pairs of [name=value]. For example:

```
"a=somevalueb=othervaluec=lastvalue"
```

I need to get the value for property b ("othervalue"). However, the properties are not in a specified order. Also, some properties (including b) may not exist at all. And the biggest problem is that the properties are not neccessarily (but may be!) seperated by anything, so I cannot split and then just get the chunk that starts with "b=". I need to find the property somehwere in the whole string.

What I know is:

- what properties can *potentially* be in the string
- that each property can occur at most once (but may not occur at all)
- and, again, of course I know the property that I want to extract

My best idea so far is to first cut off anything before the "b=" (using indexOf() and substring()), and then make a loop over all known property names and check if this property is contained, then cut it away somehow.

But I feel there might be a more elegant way. I tried with some regex, but don't really know what to extract (group(???)) as the string pattern can vary.

Thank you for your suggestions! (And btw: Implementation would be in Java, if that matters)

Comment: Are the key/value pairs delimited by some known character?  As you've written things, it looks like the value from one pair merges in with the key from the next.  Is that really the case?

Comment: yes, there is no character i can split by unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy enough to find the beginning of the value you're looking for. The trick is to find the end, since your text is badly formed.

From your description, the value ends either at the end of text (obviously), or when another known key exists.

```
b=(.*?)(?=a=|c=|d=|e=|$)
```

**Followup**

To work when the "property value can contain line breaks" (from comment), there are two ways:

- Specify [`Pattern.DOTALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) flag as second parameter to [`compile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)
- Turn the flag on in the regex: `(?s)b=(.*?)(?=a=|c=|d=|e=|$)`

Comment: Hey, thank you! I tried something like that but somehow I got confused with the groups. However, I have a problem with the "$", because the property value can actually contain line breaks. What is the character for "end of string"?

Comment: I got it: I had to replace:
(.*?)
with:
 ((.|\n|\r)*?)

Comment: sorry, even better: Leave as you said, and enable Pattern.DOTALL mode for the pattern (java)